# How to add Page Indicator to FlipView? UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, flipview

Currently I'm developing a UWP app. I want to design a welcome page when a user opens the app for the first time.

I want to use **FlipView** control to display multiple pages. But I don't have any idea how to use FlipView control and how to add **page indicator** to it.

Can anybody give me an example of a blank FlipView control with a page indicator? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for, but this little sample will create a flipview with three pages and a page indicator under it to show the index of the page.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <FlipView x:Name="FlipViewFun" Height="300">
                <FlipViewItem>
                    <TextBox Text="Hello World" />
                </FlipViewItem>
                <FlipViewItem>
                    <TextBox Text="Sweet" />
                </FlipViewItem>
                <FlipViewItem>
                    <TextBox Text="OK" />
                </FlipViewItem>
            </FlipView>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPageIndicator"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="50" 
                Text="{Binding ElementName=FlipViewFun, Path=SelectedIndex}" />
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Obviously, if you want a more realistic page indicator (for instance not starting at 0) then you'll have to add some logic (like a property) to your code-behind and then bind to it (or a view model if you decide to use MVVM pattern).